# How to write a code for n number of product of matrices and have dimension of 2*2

Tags: matrix

How can I write a matrix in product form having a dimension of 2*2 each element of matrix depend on n which depend on how many matrices we multiply?
'''A_{11}=[Xi]*{n}; A*{12}=[Eta]*{n}; A*{21}=[Gamma]*{n};A*{22}=[Alpha]_{n}'''
values of matrix element depend on n. How can I form a matrix in multiplicative form N times?N matrices will multiply and get final results.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of the calculation that you wish to perform?

Comment: Let have a matrix whose first element is A11=n^2+n, second element is A12=n^3+n^2, the third element is  A21= n^5, and the fourth element is  A22=n all element depends on n. How to construct a matrix for N =10 values it takes multiplication of all 10 matrices and gives the final output.

Answer (score 1):

(Pretty sure this is a dupe.)

This can be done with just one call to `Array[]`, using its fourth argument:

```
Array[Function[n, {{n^2 + n, n^3 + n^2}, {n^5, n}}], 6, 1, Dot]
   {{3658958632800, 520745176800}, {1829479316400, 260372588400}}

Array[Function[n, {{n^2 + n, n^3 + n^2}, {n^5, n}}], 10, 1, Dot]
   {{3907587331793831328820800000, 340977888463848983081280000},
    {1953793665896915664410400000, 170488944231924491540640000}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
mat[n_] = {{n^2 + n, n^3 + n^2}, {n^5, n}};
bigN = 6;
matrices = Map[mat, Range[bigN]];
Apply[Dot, matrices]
```

(* {{3658958632800, 520745176800}, {1829479316400, 260372588400}} *)